# K'th Min From a set of intervals

Tags: algorithm, memory, data-structures, time-complexity, min

You have given a set of intervals like {2,7} , {3,8}, {9,11} , {-4,-1} so on. The question is to find the k'th min from these set of intervals.

Also the duplicates are counted twice. For example if intervals are {1,4} and {2,6} and k = 3 then the answer is 2 because if we flatten the intervals and sort merge them then we get the sequence

```
 1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6
```

Where 3rd min is 3.

There can be a lot of ways to solve this problem. However I am struggling to find the one with minimum time / space complexity.

Comment: So if `k` is 0, then answer is -4? And for 1, answer is -1?

Comment: probably k starts from 1, so k = 1 is -4 and k =2 is -1

Comment: Added some additional things for overlapping intervals

Comment: Here is a [C++ implementation](https://ideone.com/DMwlgB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Flat the intervals.
2. Sort the flatten sequence.
3. Iterate over the sorted sequence, until you find the `k`-th element,
   while ignoring duplicate values.

---

Now let's do some analysis, where we set `N` the number of total numbers present in your intervals and `M` the average number of duplicate values a number will have (will be 1 for a unique flatten sequence).

*Space Complexity*:

> O(N)

where you could do better, if you have many duplicate elements, by iterating over the flatten sequence, while discarding the duplicate elements.

*Time Complexity*:

> O(k*M + NlogN)

- Flattening takes O(N)
- Sorting takes O(NlogN)
- Iteration takes O(k*M)